# Proftpd not working in passive mode

Tags: ftp

i have a Ubuntu server installed with proftpd. active mode works but passive mode not.
I can't get the file list and a telnet on the server says connection refused.

I read on several pages that I must configure the firewall (iptables) but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You need to create an iptables rule that allows passive connections: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-passive-ftp-is-not-working/

Comment: Used the commands from that site but now hole network is down. Is there not i simple shutdown firewall function that allows everything?

Comment: Try dropping all your rules and setting everything to allow: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html However, this should not be left as the state on a production server, as it really is worth having a firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dor.ky/virtualmin-proftpd-passive-ftp/

you’ll need to edit the iptables-config file located at:

```
[root@pluto ~]# nano /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
```

Add the end of the configuration file, add the following line:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_netbios_ns ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

You can now restart the iptables service with the following command and FTP should work through passive mode:

```
[root@pluto ~]# service iptables restart
```